# Why doesn't water wash off the coronavirus alone?

Tags: organic-chemistry

So the coronavirus has a lipid bilayer where the hydrophilic heads are facing outward. So why can't water just stick to these ends and flush out the virus particles from our hands? Is it because our hands stick better to the virus? If so, why and how does the virus stick better to our hands than water?

Answer (score 2):

Because your hands are covered in a thick crust of dirt, dust and fats, in which the virus can hide.

But anyway still nobody has been able to show that this virus is regularily (or even rarely) transmitted via smear infection. (If someone knows about any evidence to the contrary, please come forward. And yes, some other diseases, especially bacterial infections, do even *mainly* take this route. That´s how you usually get the "shits".)

It can be detected on surfaces after hours via PCR, however PCR is as sensitive to broken down pieces of a virus particle as it is to the fresh, contagious specimen. Obviously the RNA pieces also of a destroyed virus would not evaporate, so the result of these investigations proves nothing but the extremely obvious. Newspapers are spreading it as a piece of clickbait and tinder, causing people to buy lots of "sanitizers".

Anyway, use soap, leave the disinfectants to the health care people who *absolutely, direly need them*, and be done.

Comment: We shouldn't be commenting on any questions about Covid-19 due to the medical exclusion.

Comment: I think the non-polar fatty part  of the soap damage the  lipid bilayer of virus causing it dysfunction and the polar part  of the soap attracted to the water.

Comment: It might be somehow similiar to "why not to use just water while washing hands". Washing would remove the virus. Soap even more by 1) disrupting it and 2) by removing other dirt in which it can be. I feel free to comment as for the message is WASH YOUR HANDS WITH WATER AND SOAP frequently. I also feel to add STAY AT HOME. Many places are still behind Italy so get the message. Here we did a lot even at beginning, simply wasn't enough.

Comment: It has now been tried to find "viable" viruses, i.e. ones that can be replicated in a cell culture, on all kinds of surfaces in households where multiple currently infected and contagious people live. Everything is full of virus RNA (detected via PCR), but no success. Which is hardly a surprise.